# Issues with multiple date pickers in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, jquery, datepicker

We are using two date fields in our template, as the first field is working fine but when we select the second field, the date is getting applied or changed to the first field.

I am using below code for rendering,

In the template.

```
    <input class="input-text" type="text" data-bind="datepicker: true"  name="delivery_date" id="delivery_date" readonly="true"/> 


    <input class="input-text" type="text" data-bind="datepickertwo: true"  name="delivery_date" id="delivery_date" readonly="true"/>
```

Date field one

```
ko.bindingHandlers.datepicker = {
                    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
                        var $el = $(element);    
                    //initialize datepicker with some optional options
                        if(noday) {
                            var options = {
                                minDate: 0,
                                dateFormat:format,
                                hourMin: hourMin,
                                hourMax: hourMax
                            };
                        } else {
                            var options = {
                                minDate: 0,
                                dateFormat:format,
                                hourMin: hourMin,
                                hourMax: hourMax,
                                beforeShowDay: function(date) {
                                    var day = date.getDay();
                                    if(disabledDay.indexOf(day) > -1) {
                                        return [false];
                                    } else {
                                        return [true];
                                    }
                                }
                            };
                        }


                    $el.datepicker(options);

                    var writable = valueAccessor();
                    if (!ko.isObservable(writable)) {
                        var propWriters = allBindingsAccessor()._ko_property_writers;
                        if (propWriters && propWriters.datepicker) {
                            writable = propWriters.datepicker;
                        } else {
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    writable($(element).datepicker("getDate"));

                },
                update: function(element, valueAccessor)   {
                    var widget = $(element).data("DateTimePicker");
                    //when the view model is updated, update the widget
                    if (widget) {
                        var date = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
                        widget.date(date);
                    }
                }
            };
```

Date field two

```
ko.bindingHandlers.datepickertwo = {
                    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
                        var $el = $(element);    
                        if(noday) {
                            var options = {
                                minDate: 0,
                                dateFormat:format,
                                hourMin: hourMin,
                                hourMax: hourMax
                            };
                        } else {
                            var options = {
                                minDate: 0,
                                dateFormat:format,
                                hourMin: hourMin,
                                hourMax: hourMax,
                                beforeShowDay: function(date) {
                                    var day = date.getDay();
                                    if(disabledDay.indexOf(day) > -1) {
                                        return [false];
                                    } else {
                                        return [true];
                                    }
                                }
                            };
                        }
                    $el.datepicker(options);
                    var writable = valueAccessor();
                    if (!ko.isObservable(writable)) {
                        var propWriters = allBindingsAccessor()._ko_property_writers;
                        if (propWriters && propWriters.datepickertwo) {
                            writable = propWriters.datepickertwo;
                        } else {
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    writable($(element).datepickertwo("getDate"));

                },
                update: function(element, valueAccessor)   {
                    var widget = $(element).data("DateTimePicker");
                    //when the view model is updated, update the widget
                    if (widget) {
                        var date = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
                        widget.date(date);
                    }
                }
            };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue, as i have to use different or unique id's for input field.

```
<input class="input-text" type="text" data-bind="datepicker: true"  name="delivery_date" id="delivery_date" readonly="true"/> 

<input class="input-text" type="text" data-bind="datepickertwo: true"  name="delivery_date_two" id="delivery_date_two" readonly="true"/>
```